# display sqlite database as a table in paygames

Tags: python, sqlite, pygame

I'm trying to display a basic SQLite database as a table in pygame. It holds the players username and score. The code I have now displays it but it doesn't aligne nicely. The code:

```
def leader_board():
    i = 35
    messg = font_style.render(f'PLAYER                  SCORE', True, yellow)
    dis.blit(messg, [dis_width / 5, (700 / 4) + 5])
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM snake_score ORDER BY score desc LIMIT 10')

    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        mesgg = font_style.render('{:>3} {:30}'.format(row[0], row[1]), True, yellow)
        dis.blit(mesgg, [dis_width / 5, (700 / 4) + i + 5])
        i += 35
```

This is the result that I get from it:
[image]

I'd like the numbers to be all aligned with the end of the word 'score'. Any help would be appreciated because I have tried some things and none seemed to work.

Comment: Either use a monospace font or render the text of each column separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a monospace font or render the text of each column separately:

```py
def leader_board():
    i = 35
    column_space = 400

    head1 = font_style.render(f'PLAYER', True, yellow)
    head2 = font_style.render(f'SCORE', True, yellow)
    dis.blit(head1, [dis_width / 5, (700 / 4) + 5])
    dis.blit(head2, [dis_width / 5 + column_space, (700 / 4) + 5])
    
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM snake_score ORDER BY score desc LIMIT 10')
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        
        column1 = font_style.render('{:>3}'.format(row[0]), True, yellow)
        column2 = font_style.render('{:30}'.format(row[1]), True, yellow)
        dis.blit(column1, [dis_width / 5, (700 / 4) + i + 5])
        dis.blit(column2, [dis_width / 5 + column_space, (700 / 4) + i + 5])

        i += 35
```